# How to make recursive in sql alchemy

Tags: mysql, recursion, sqlalchemy

`

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTS AS (
    SELECT board_rid, SUBJECT, lv, parent_rid, CAST(board_rid as CHAR(100)) depth
    FROM board_tbl
    WHERE parent_rid = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.board_rid, b.SUBJECT, b.lv, b.parent_rid, CONCAT(c.depth, ",", b.board_rid) depth
    FROM board_tbl b
    INNER JOIN CTS c
    ON b.parent_rid = c.board_rid
)
SELECT board_rid, subject, parent_rid, lv, depth
from CTS
ORDER BY depth
```

`

I use mysql and I want to this sql to sqlalchemy.

How do I change it?

[image: DB]

Comment: What's the problem? If you get an error post the error message, If does not work as expected publish sample data and desired outcome. AND state your mysql version (CTEs not available before version 8)

Comment: This should get you started: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#common-table-expressions-cte